# Rails query comparing against Postgres Array Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

So i have a this column in a table
`t.text "foo", default: [], array: true`

And i have this array list in a helper file,

```
module HelperData

  Helper_array = [
    "data_1",
    "data_2",
    "data_3",
    "data_4",
    "data_5"
  ]
end
```

Inside the `FooName.rb` model there's a line `include HelperData`.

So the query i want to pass is the include operator `&&` in comparing PG arrays, based on this [Postgres Guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html).

I have tried the following queries:

`FooName.where("foo" && HelperData::Helper_array)`. This query returns the error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:`. The syntax error is with the elements in `HelperData::Helper_array`. I have a slight hunch that it is because `Foo` is `:text` but the data in `Helper_array` is a `string`, though i can't be certain.

`FooName.where("foo && HelperData::Helper_array")`. This query returns the error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:`. Obviously this is just the wrong syntax then.

What is the proper query to find whether the `foo` array has any elements that overlap with the `Helper_array`, and return all `FooName` objects that has overlapping elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
FooName.where("foo && ARRAY[?]::text[]", HelperData::Helper_array)
```

refer this link
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text[] && character varying[]` Throws this error.

Comment: em, sorry for that, find out that the column is `text` type, not `string` type. so try `FooName.where("foo && ARRAY[?]::text[]", HelperData::Helper_array)`. i have test it in my rails console, it's working.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll test it out and check your answer as correct if it works! :)